# Setting opacity / alpha on rgba in css variable

Tags: css, atom-editor, css-variables

I am trying out CSS variables and I would like to use RGB colours.

Here's my current CSS Variable:

```
--primary: rgb(112, 199, 255);
```

So this works absolutely fine when using the following code:

```
color: var(--primary)
```

But some paragraphs also use this primary colour and I would like to give them a slight transparency. Now I could replace that and create another CSS Variable like so:

```
--primary: rgb(112, 199, 255);    
--primary-alpha: rgba(112, 199, 255, 0.7);
```

But that just feels messy and confusing having two primary colours and what If I use a few different transparencies. I could also use the following CSS Variable:

```
--primary: 112, 199, 255;
--alpha: 0.7;
```

and output it using the following code:

```
color: rgba(var(--white), var(--alpha));
```

This works as I want and I personally think is a nicer way of doing it but my colours don't preview in my code editor see image.

[image]

Look at the --dark variable, it won't show the colour using this code.

Ideally, I would like to use:

```
--primary: rgb(112, 199, 255);
```

and output it like so:

```
color: var(--white), var(--alpha);
```

But it won't work?

Comment: _“Look at the --dark variable, it won't show the colour using this code”_ - and why should it, seeing as the value is _not_ a color, but just three comma-separated numbers …?

Comment: Exactly, but by doing it that way I can use color: rgba(var(--white), var(--alpha)); to output the RGB and also change the alpha

Comment: what made you say `--dark: 18, 38, 51` will not work? Its just a variable. It will when you use it in a color property like `rgba(var(--dark), 0.5);` It should. You saying you tried this and didn't work ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa No, --dark works just fine, it just doesn't show when i'm coding, it makes it far easier for me to read when I can see the colours. I need to use rgb or rgba for Atom to show the colours but doiing it that way stops me adding the alpha as and when I want if that makes sense

Comment: @Dan - Well, editor would definitely not detect since its not part of any property yet. You might as well put any value in its place. Guess that's a compromise you have to make. **Perhaps adding a comment besides the variable might help**?

Comment: @Dan -  Im assuming you are using [atom-pigments](https://github.com/abe33/atom-pigments). There is a video i can see where they have included the color in comment and it detects within comments. So maybe you can use something like `--dark: 18, 38, 51 /* just to prompt - rgb(18, 38, 51) */`

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa Yeah, that's what I am using. Your comment idea works a charm. Thank you. If you want to submit an answer I'll mark it as complete otherwise I'll just delete te question

Comment: Sure, this can surely help others. will post an answer

Comment: You really should have specified what editor you were using from the get-go, since this is clearly a question related to the editor and not CSS alone (otherwise, as others have mentioned, the custom props work exactly as intended).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using [atom-pigment](https://github.com/abe33/atom-pigments). The color detection works within comments as well. So you could perhaps add the actual rgb value in the comments only for reference & use the variable as usual. Like so:

```
--dark: 18, 38, 51 /* this color is - rgb(18, 38, 51) */
```